# Windows Server 2003 NLB drainstop notification on stop

Tags: windows-server-2003, load-balancing

How would I drainstop one of the nodes in a MS NLB via command line and then get notified of its completion?

If there's no way to callback, is there an easy way to poll?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772833.aspx has it all.

Run the drainstop and then query until it is drained.

**nlb query *yourServer***